# Cartodb add basemap switcher

Tags: javascript, leaflet, carto, carto-js, basemap

I currently have a map created entirely in the CartoDB editor, including custom map. For some reason it doesn't allow you to add an attribution in the editor but thats a different problem.

So my map has a custom baselayer and 3 toggleable layers. Here is the code.

```
<script>
  function main() {
    cartodb.createVis('map', 'https://paulm.cartodb.com/api/v2/viz/5fd91fc8/viz.json', {
    })
    .done(function(vis, layers) {
      window.layers = layers;
    })
    .error(function(err) {
      console.log(err);
    });
  }
  window.onload = main;
</script>
```

I know that I could replace the current base map by adding

```
.done(function(vis, layers) {
  var basemap = layers[0];
  basemap.setUrl('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png');
})
```

However im not sure if its possible to enable a base map switcher, or if I need to add it as a new layer completely will I need to do that via the code. Adding in a whole new set of tiles seems to be more of a basemap switch than just a data layer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can! Actually I built something similar in this example some weeks ago (the basemap switcher doesn't look great, but the functionality is there): http://bl.ocks.org/iriberri/08abc420a376053c71d4

You can just save the basemap layer into a variable and change its _url parameter. Then, just redraw it:

```
      basemap._url="http://stamen-tiles-{s}.a.ssl.fastly.net/toner/{z}/{x}/{y}.png";
      basemap.redraw();
```

Copying here the whole source code for the record too:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Basemap example | CartoDB.js</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://cartodb.com/assets/favicon.ico" />
    <style>
      html, body, #map {
        height: 90%;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
      }
    </style>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://libs.cartocdn.com/cartodb.js/v3/3.15/themes/css/cartodb.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>

    <button type="button" id="button-basemap1" onclick="setBasemap1();"> Basemap 1</button>

    <button type="button" id="button-basemap2" onclick="setBasemap2();"> Basemap 2</button>


    <!-- include cartodb.js library -->
    <script src="http://libs.cartocdn.com/cartodb.js/v3/3.15/cartodb.js"></script>

    <script>
        var basemap;

       function setBasemap1(){
          basemap._url="http://stamen-tiles-{s}.a.ssl.fastly.net/toner/{z}/{x}/{y}.png";
          basemap.redraw();
        }

        function setBasemap2(){
          basemap._url="http://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/light_all/{z}/{x}/{y}.png";
          basemap.redraw();

        }
      function main() {

        cartodb.createVis('map', 'http://documentation.cartodb.com/api/v2/viz/2b13c956-e7c1-11e2-806b-5404a6a683d5/viz.json')
        .done(function(vis, layers) {

         basemap = layers[0];


        })
        .error(function(err) {
          console.log(err);
        });
      }
      window.onload = main;
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```